# When were list-columns introduced in tidyverse and data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Hoping this question is not deemed off-topic. I am curious whether the tidyverse family of packages (or whatever precursor existed at that time) or data.table adopted the list-column data structure first. Was one inspired by the other to do so? Where did the idea for this type of data structure originate?

Comment: Looks like `tidyr::nest` was introduced in 2015: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#new-features-2

Comment: `data.table` seems have have had from the beginning (2008) or close to the beginning: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was also curious more broadly, whether there is any older example of a "data frame" like structure that allows nested list columns, whether in R or another language

Comment: I'd really love if data.table could group by some variable, which would then be nested as data.tables - this is possible, but all the cool .SD, .N and so on functions can't work with that. Here, tidyverse seems to have the upper hand

Comment: @emilBeBri check out this neat function by TS Barrett to group a DT by variable(s) and nest it into a listcolumn of DTs: https://osf.io/f6pxw/download . I modified it and incorporated it into a R package our organization uses.

Comment: Yes I already found that!  :) pretty cool, it's a step in right direction. however, It still seemed kind of error-prone to me. All the .SD and .N stuff I need can't be nested, or at least I coulnd't figure out how to. Perhaps I'll make a QA and link it here, seems like you have been experimenting with it. Is the source code for your package on github, so I can see how you apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was there from the very beginning by the fact that both those classes inherits from data.frame, where list support was already there.

```r
iris$l = vector("list", 150)
head(iris)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    l
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa NULL
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa NULL
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa NULL
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa NULL
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa NULL
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa NULL
```

How well all operations are supported for `list` column type is a different question, which is changing over years, also for base R.